# Correct usage of setting a variable (i of for loop) as a class selector in Jade

Tags: pug

I'm trying to make an ordered list with each item having a class as its respective ordinal

```html
<ol>
  <li class="1">1</li>
  <li class="2">2</li>
  <li class="3">3</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

By using a for loop in Jade

```jade
ol
    - for(var i= 1; i<=8; i++){
    li(class='!{i}') !{i}
    - }
```

However it isn't working

[image]

What needs to be corrected here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string interpolation syntax is `#{variable}`, not `!{variable}`:

```
li(class='#{i}') !{i}
// or simply
li(class=i) !{i}
```

Also, when you use `!{i}` vs `#{i}` for the content of the `li`, the former will have HTML entities escaped while the latter will not.